# how to check if all inputs in page not empty

Tags: javascript

I currently have 6 inputs in my page. If none of them is empty, it should set inputsCheckState = true.

But what is happening is if only one input is not empty, my code sets inputsCheckState = true.

How can I fix this bug?

This is my code at the moment:

```
inputs.forEach(e => {
            if (e.required && e.value.length === 0) {
                console.log(e.value.length)
                if (message === null) {
                    doneMessage('../../../../assets/images/alarm.svg', 'برجاء ملئ جميع الحقول المطلوبه', '', 'حسناً')
                    inputsCheckState = false
                }
            } else if (e.required && e.value.length !== 0) {
                inputsCheckState = true
            }
        });
```

Comment: This question lacks the necessary context(code) that you are interacting with, please post all relevant information.

Comment: Note `e` generally denotes `event` which isn't what is being iterated over here. It might make more sense to rename it to `input`.

Comment: How are you running that code? Is it run on the click of a button, or are you running it on every input change event?

Comment: You should initialize inputsCheckState to true, assuming all required inputs are non-empty. Then, for each input, if we find any required input that is empty, we set inputsCheckState to false. However, we do not set it to true inside the loop because that would be premature; we want to make sure all inputs have been checked before setting inputsCheckState to true. I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce the `inputs` node-list to an array so you can use the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) array method.

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function doneMessage(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

function handleClick() {

  const inputsCheckState = [...inputs].every(input => {
    return input.required && input.value.length;
  });

  if (!inputsCheckState) {
    doneMessage('Input(s) not complete');
  } else {
    console.log('Inputs complete');
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text" required>
<button type="button">Check inputs</button>
```